# Best way to lock down a website ecommerce basket while going to PSP

Tags: php, e-commerce

I know this question may not have a "right" answer but any answers would be appreciated. I'm probably going to get flamed for this.

Is there a best practice for locking down a basket while the customer goes off to a payment provider to pay for an order.

For example: I want to stop customers who have 1 x $10 item in basket – goes off to PSP to pay but then changes basket qty to 10 before they have completed the transaction. In my system the order quantity is 10 but they have only paid for 1.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing to close up is making it impossible to change the order items (products) after the transaction has completed. theres a bunch of different ways to do that. personally i think the safest is to have a separate tables for

"items in a cart while shopping" 
VS 
"items that are part of a completed order".

so **if possible have a separate table for the items that are part of a completed order**. they are created right after the transaction has completed - and the customer does not have access to them at all. if the customer is able to change the items in their cart after the transaction -- it will not change the order.

otherwise remember **its not a problem until after the transaction is approved**. a customer should be able to have a failed transaction - get their second credit card - change something in their cart - and then submit again.

a related idea is to flag the shopping session when the transaction has gone through. then if for whatever reason the customer clicks on the back button and tries to change the quantities in a cart after an order - the existing session won't confirm - a new session will be created and the cart will be empty.

Comment: Thanks Cartalot,the user can't change the basket amounts after the transaction is processed but rather during the transaction.So,  while the user is on the paypal screen for example entering their login info. I might , however, use your suggestion of flagging the session when they navigate to the PSP.